# Is there any way to set the default route action to be the same name as the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC2 application.

After having about 10 tabs open that read "Default.aspx" I was wondering if there was a way to specify in the routing table that the default controller action should be the same name as the controller.  So for example, if I go to http://mysite/Foo, it would invoke the action Foo in the controller Foo which will then return the default ViewResult that points to Foo.aspx.

If it's not possible, then it's no big deal since I can specify the name of the view anyway in the View method.  But it would be nice if it could be done.

Comment: Why do you want exactly same name? Default action for you controller Foo is Index. So if you go to http://mysite/Foo - action Index will work and it is similar to http://mysite/Foo/Index. ALso you can add default routing in Global.asax

Comment: The default action is Index if you don't change it.  In my case, I changed it so that the default action was Default.  It's just a matter of taste.  Now, the reason why I want the default action to be the same name as the controller is so that when I look at it in Visual Studio, I can quickly find the source file I want instead of seeing 10 Default.aspx tabs (or Index.aspx if you prefer).  If you think about this, this isn't too weird since in many languages the constructor is the same name as the class.  I want my default action to be the same name as the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BaseController that all your controllers extend from, which automatically redirects your default "Index" action to an action of the same name as the current controller route parameter.

I don't think it's possible to define this in the route registry though.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your needs. But it seems to me, it is not a good practice to change routing of your application to meet you demands for your development environment.

You can quick jump from View to Controller with action that return this View, e.t.c. Solution for you problem is in organizing your work.

Comment: My work is organized.  Hence the problem.  Basically the default action in the controller is Default.  Since they are all in their respective view folders, all I see in my editor tab is Default.aspx.  Also, I realize that at the end of the day, humans, not computers are editing my source files.  I shouldn't have to make the humans work towards making the computer happy, but make the computer work with what makes coding more practical to the user.